# Problem after upgrading: table not found

Tags: upgrade, debugging, installation

I have a big issue after installing an upgrade of CIVICRM.

The debug output indicates a table is missing but does not identify which one:
DB Error: no such table

What should I do?

I have add a debug line to see what is happening :

```
CRM_Core_DAO_Domain: CONNECT: Checking for database specific ini ('') : database_ in options
CRM_Core_DAO_Domain: QUERY: /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */
CRM_Core_DAO_Domain: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00063800811767578 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO_Domain: QUERY: SET NAMES utf8
CRM_Core_DAO_Domain: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00042486190795898 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO_Domain: find: 1
CRM_Core_DAO_Domain: QUERY: SELECT *, config_backend, locales, locale_custom_strings 
FROM civicrm_domain 

WHERE ( civicrm_domain.id = 1 ) 




CRM_Core_DAO_Domain: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00088405609130859 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO_Domain: find: CHECK autofetchd 1
CRM_Core_DAO_Domain: find: ABOUT TO AUTOFETCH
CRM_Core_DAO_Domain: FETCH: a:8:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:4:"name";s:45:"Connaissance et Vie d'Aujourd'hui - Charleroi";s:11:"description";s:22:"Association culturelle";s:14:"config_backend";s:2955:"a:79:{s:18:"dateformatDatetime";s:14:"%E %B %Y %Hh%M";s:14:"dateformatFull";s:8:"%E %B %Y";s:17:"dateformatPartial";s:5:"%B %Y";s:14:"dateformatYear";s:2:"%Y";s:14:"dateformatTime";s:5:"%Hh%M";s:15:"dateInputFormat";s:8:"dd/mm/yy";s:15:"fiscalYearStart";a:2:{s:1:"M";s:1:"1";s:1:"d";s:1:"1";}s:15:"civiRelativeURL";s:44:"/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&amp;task=";s:21:"includeWildCardInName";s:1:"1";s:18:"includeEmailInName";s:1:"1";s:21:"includeNickNameInName";s:1:"0";s:24:"includeAlphabeticalPager";s:1:"1";s:20:"includeOrderByClause";s:1:"1";s:22:"smartGroupCacheTimeout";s:1:"0";s:22:"defaultSearchProfileID";s:0:"";s:10:"lcMessages";s:5:"fr_FR";s:25:"monetaryThousandSeparator";s:1:",";s:20:"monetaryDecimalPoint";s:1:".";s:11:"moneyformat";s:5:"%c %a";s:16:"moneyvalueformat";s:3:"%!i";s:12:"countryLimit";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"1020";}s:13:"provinceLimit";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"1020";}s:21:"defaultContactCountry";s:4:"1020";s:15:"defaultCurrency";s:3:"EUR";s:14:"legacyEncoding";s:12:"Windows-1252";s:23:"customTranslateFunction";s:0:"";s:14:"fieldSeparator";s:1:",";s:11:"_qf_default";s:17:"Localization:next";s:21:"_qf_Localization_next";s:4:"Save";s:13:"inheritLocale";i:0;s:21:"defaultCurrencySymbol";s:3:"â‚¬";s:16:"enableComponents";a:5:{i:0;s:10:"CiviMember";i:1;s:9:"CiviEvent";i:2;s:8:"CiviMail";i:3;s:10:"CiviReport";i:4;s:14:"CiviContribute";}s:18:"enableComponentIDs";a:5:{i:0;s:1:"3";i:1;s:1:"1";i:2;s:1:"4";i:3;s:1:"8";i:4;s:1:"2";}s:11:"mapProvider";s:6:"Google";s:9:"mapAPIKey";s:0:"";s:11:"geoProvider";s:6:"Google";s:9:"geoAPIKey";s:0:"";s:10:"userSystem";O:23:"CRM_Utils_System_Joomla":4:{s:9:"is_drupal";b:0;s:9:"is_joomla";b:0;s:12:"is_wordpress";b:0;s:24:"supports_form_extensions";b:0;}s:11:"initialized";i:0;s:15:"DAOFactoryClass";s:23:"CRM_Contact_DAO_Factory";s:17:"componentRegistry";O:18:"CRM_Core_Component":0:{}s:9:"inCiviCRM";b:0;s:18:"recaptchaPublicKey";N;s:5:"debug";i:0;s:9:"backtrace";i:0;s:12:"resourceBase";N;s:15:"timeInputFormat";i:1;s:15:"currencySymbols";s:0:"";s:14:"gettextCodeset";s:5:"utf-8";s:13:"gettextDomain";s:7:"civicrm";s:27:"userFrameworkUsersTableName";s:9:"jos_users";s:21:"userFrameworkFrontend";b:0;s:20:"userFrameworkLogging";b:0;s:17:"maxImportFileSize";i:1048576;s:14:"maxAttachments";i:3;s:11:"maxFileSize";i:2;s:13:"geocodeMethod";s:0:"";s:12:"mapGeoCoding";i:1;s:15:"contactUndelete";b:1;s:7:"logging";b:0;s:12:"versionCheck";b:1;s:11:"civiModules";a:0:{}s:9:"enableSSL";b:0;s:18:"fatalErrorTemplate";s:20:"CRM/common/fatal.tpl";s:17:"fatalErrorHandler";N;s:17:"maxLocationBlocks";i:2;s:15:"captchaFontPath";s:25:"/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/";s:11:"captchaFont";s:17:"HelveticaBold.ttf";s:21:"dashboardCacheTimeout";i:1440;s:15:"doNotResetCache";i:0;s:13:"oldInputStyle";i:1;s:14:"formKeyDisable";b:0;s:21:"doNotAttachPDFReceipt";b:0;s:13:"verpSeparator";s:1:".";s:12:"mailerPeriod";i:180;s:16:"mailerSpoolLimit";i:0;s:16:"mailerBatchLimit";i:0;s:13:"mailerJobSize";i:0;s:13:"mailerJobsMax";i:0;}";s:7:"version";s:5:"4.1.5";s:12:"loc_block_id";s:1:"2";s:7:"locales";N;s:21:"locale_custom_strings";s:453:"a:1:{s:5:"fr_FR";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";a:2:{s:13:"wildcardMatch";a:0:{}s:10:"exactMatch";a:0:{}}s:8:"disabled";a:2:{s:13:"wildcardMatch";a:9:{s:11:"Ã©vÃ©nement";s:9:"activitÃ©";s:7:"Billing";s:11:"Facturation";s:4:"Save";s:11:"Enregistrer";s:3:"and";s:2:"et";s:3:"New";s:7:"nouveau";s:12:"Contribution";s:8:"paiement";s:3:"Add";s:7:"Ajouter";s:4:"Both";s:8:"Les deux";s:7:"Address";s:7:"adresse";}s:10:"exactMatch";a:1:{s:7:"Pending";s:10:"En attente";}}}}";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Domain: find: DONE
CRM_Core_DAO: CONNECT: Checking for database specific ini ('') : database_ in options
CRM_Core_DAO: QUERY: SET NAMES utf8
CRM_Core_DAO: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00046706199645996 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO: CONNECT: Checking for database specific ini ('') : database_ in options
CRM_Core_DAO: QUERY: SET NAMES utf8
CRM_Core_DAO: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00047397613525391 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO: QUERY: 
SELECT name, group_name, value
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE ( group_name = 'Directory Preferences'
OR group_name = 'URL Preferences' )
AND domain_id = 1

CRM_Core_DAO: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00061798095703125 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:4:"name";s:9:"uploadDir";s:10:"group_name";s:21:"Directory Preferences";s:5:"value";s:14:"s:7:"upload/";";}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:4:"name";s:14:"imageUploadDir";s:10:"group_name";s:21:"Directory Preferences";s:5:"value";s:27:"s:19:"persist/contribute/";";}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:4:"name";s:19:"customFileUploadDir";s:10:"group_name";s:21:"Directory Preferences";s:5:"value";s:14:"s:7:"custom/";";}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:4:"name";s:17:"customTemplateDir";s:10:"group_name";s:21:"Directory Preferences";s:5:"value";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:4:"name";s:16:"customPHPPathDir";s:10:"group_name";s:21:"Directory Preferences";s:5:"value";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:4:"name";s:13:"extensionsDir";s:10:"group_name";s:21:"Directory Preferences";s:5:"value";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:4:"name";s:24:"userFrameworkResourceURL";s:10:"group_name";s:15:"URL Preferences";s:5:"value";s:53:"s:45:"administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/";";}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:4:"name";s:14:"imageUploadURL";s:10:"group_name";s:15:"URL Preferences";s:5:"value";s:41:"s:33:"media/civicrm/persist/contribute/";";}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:4:"name";s:12:"customCSSURL";s:10:"group_name";s:15:"URL Preferences";s:5:"value";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: N;
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: Last Data Fetch'ed after 0.0010199546813965 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: CONNECT: Checking for database specific ini ('') : database_ in options
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: QUERY: SET NAMES utf8
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00049209594726562 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: find: 
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: QUERY: SELECT * 
FROM civicrm_setting 

WHERE ( civicrm_setting.group_name = 'CiviCRM Preferences' ) AND ( civicrm_setting.domain_id = 1 ) AND ( civicrm_setting.is_domain = 1 ) 




CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00073695182800293 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: find: CHECK autofetchd 
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: find: DONE
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:2:"12";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:30:"activity_assignee_notification";s:5:"value";s:4:"i:1;";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-19 03:15:52";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:1:"6";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:14:"address_format";s:5:"value";s:179:"s:170:"{contact.address_name}
{contact.street_address}
{contact.supplemental_address_1}
{contact.supplemental_address_2}
{contact.postal_code}{ }{contact.city}
{contact.country}";";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-18 12:34:39";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:1:"5";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:15:"address_options";s:5:"value";s:21:"s:13:"123459";";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-18 12:34:39";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:1:"3";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:23:"advanced_search_options";s:5:"value";s:42:"s:34:"1234567891013161719";";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-19 03:15:52";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:2:"11";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:26:"contact_ajax_check_similar";s:5:"value";s:4:"i:1;";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-19 03:15:52";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:2:"13";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:28:"contact_autocomplete_options";s:5:"value";s:10:"s:3:"1";";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-19 11:12:19";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:1:"2";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:20:"contact_edit_options";s:5:"value";s:26:"s:18:"123457811";";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-19 03:15:52";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:2:"14";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:25:"contact_reference_options";s:5:"value";s:10:"s:3:"1";";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-19 11:12:19";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:20:"contact_view_options";s:5:"value";s:26:"s:18:"123468910";";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-19 03:15:52";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:1:"8";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:19:"display_name_format";s:5:"value";s:111:"s:102:"{contact.individual_prefix}{ }{contact.first_name}{ }{contact.last_name}{ }{contact.individual_suffix}";";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-19 03:15:52";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:2:"10";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:9:"editor_id";s:5:"value";s:8:"s:1:"2";";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-19 03:15:52";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:1:"7";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:14:"mailing_format";s:5:"value";s:176:"s:167:"{contact.addressee}
{contact.street_address}
{contact.supplemental_address_1}
{contact.supplemental_address_2}
{contact.postal_code}{ }{contact.city}
{contact.country}";";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-18 12:34:39";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:1:"9";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:16:"sort_name_format";s:5:"value";s:51:"s:43:"{contact.last_name}{, }{contact.first_name}";";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-19 03:15:52";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: a:10:{s:2:"id";s:1:"4";s:10:"group_name";s:19:"CiviCRM Preferences";s:4:"name";s:22:"user_dashboard_options";s:5:"value";s:16:"s:9:"1345";";s:9:"domain_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"contact_id";N;s:9:"is_domain";s:1:"1";s:12:"component_id";N;s:12:"created_date";s:19:"2012-07-19 03:15:52";s:10:"created_id";s:1:"1";}
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: N;
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: FETCH: Last Data Fetch'ed after 0.0021209716796875 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO_Setting: 1: Clearing Cache for crm_core_dao_setting
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: CONNECT: Checking for database specific ini ('') : database_ in options
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: QUERY: SET NAMES utf8
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00047802925109863 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: find: 
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: QUERY: SELECT * 
FROM civicrm_cache 

WHERE ( civicrm_cache.group_name = 'ed50fd1f927546a457b32960d2469b00' ) 




CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00069308280944824 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: find: CHECK autofetchd 
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: find: DONE
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: 1: Clearing Cache for crm_core_dao_cache
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: CONNECT: Checking for database specific ini ('') : database_ in options
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: QUERY: SET NAMES utf8
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00046586990356445 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: find: 1
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: QUERY: SELECT * 
FROM civicrm_cache 

WHERE ( civicrm_cache.group_name = 'ed50fd1f927546a457b32960d2469b00' ) AND ( civicrm_cache.path = 'mapper/moduleFiles' ) 




CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00062990188598633 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: find: CHECK autofetchd 1
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: find: DONE
CRM_Core_DAO_Cache: 1: Clearing Cache for crm_core_dao_cache
CRM_Core_DAO: CONNECT: Checking for database specific ini ('') : database_ in options
CRM_Core_DAO: QUERY: SET NAMES utf8
CRM_Core_DAO: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00042104721069336 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO: QUERY: 
SELECT full_name, file
FROM civicrm_extension
WHERE is_active = 1
AND type = "module"

CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact: CONNECT: Checking for database specific ini ('') : database_ in options
CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact: QUERY: SET NAMES utf8
CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00041103363037109 seconds
CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact: 1: Clearing Cache for crm_contact_bao_contact
CRM_Core_DAO: CONNECT: Checking for database specific ini ('') : database_ in options
CRM_Core_DAO: QUERY: SET NAMES utf8
CRM_Core_DAO: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00046300888061523 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO: QUERY: 
SELECT v.label as label ,v.name as value, v.grouping as grouping
FROM civicrm_option_value v,
civicrm_option_group g
WHERE v.option_group_id = g.id
AND g.name = 'languages'
AND g.is_active = 1 AND v.is_active = 1 ORDER BY v.weight
CRM_Core_DAO: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00060510635375977 seconds
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:9:"Afrikaans";s:5:"value";s:5:"af_ZA";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:8:"Albanian";s:5:"value";s:5:"sq_AL";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Arabic";s:5:"value";s:5:"ar_EG";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:9:"Bulgarian";s:5:"value";s:5:"bg_BG";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:18:"Catalan; Valencian";s:5:"value";s:5:"ca_ES";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:15:"Chinese (China)";s:5:"value";s:5:"zh_CN";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:16:"Chinese (Taiwan)";s:5:"value";s:5:"zh_TW";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:5:"Czech";s:5:"value";s:5:"cs_CZ";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Danish";s:5:"value";s:5:"da_DK";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:5:"Dutch";s:5:"value";s:5:"nl_NL";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:19:"English (Australia)";s:5:"value";s:5:"en_AU";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:16:"English (Canada)";s:5:"value";s:5:"en_CA";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:24:"English (United Kingdom)";s:5:"value";s:5:"en_GB";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:23:"English (United States)";s:5:"value";s:5:"en_US";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:8:"Estonian";s:5:"value";s:5:"et_EE";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Finnish";s:5:"value";s:5:"fi_FI";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:15:"French (Canada)";s:5:"value";s:5:"fr_CA";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:15:"French (France)";s:5:"value";s:5:"fr_FR";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:6:"German";s:5:"value";s:5:"de_DE";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:14:"German (Swiss)";s:5:"value";s:5:"de_CH";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:13:"Greek, Modern";s:5:"value";s:5:"el_GR";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:15:"Hebrew (modern)";s:5:"value";s:5:"he_IL";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:5:"Hindi";s:5:"value";s:5:"hi_IN";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:9:"Hungarian";s:5:"value";s:5:"hu_HU";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:10:"Indonesian";s:5:"value";s:5:"id_ID";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Italian";s:5:"value";s:5:"it_IT";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:8:"Japanese";s:5:"value";s:5:"ja_JP";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:5:"Khmer";s:5:"value";s:5:"km_KH";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:10:"Lithuanian";s:5:"value";s:5:"lt_LT";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:17:"Norwegian BokmÃ¥l";s:5:"value";s:5:"nb_NO";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Polish";s:5:"value";s:5:"pl_PL";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:19:"Portuguese (Brazil)";s:5:"value";s:5:"pt_BR";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:21:"Portuguese (Portugal)";s:5:"value";s:5:"pt_PT";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:29:"Romanian, Moldavian, Moldovan";s:5:"value";s:5:"ro_RO";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Russian";s:5:"value";s:5:"ru_RU";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Slovak";s:5:"value";s:5:"sk_SK";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Slovene";s:5:"value";s:5:"sl_SI";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:26:"Spanish; Castilian (Spain)";s:5:"value";s:5:"es_ES";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:27:"Spanish; Castilian (Mexico)";s:5:"value";s:5:"es_MX";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:32:"Spanish; Castilian (Puerto Rico)";s:5:"value";s:5:"es_PR";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Swedish";s:5:"value";s:5:"sv_SE";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Telugu";s:5:"value";s:5:"te_IN";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:4:"Thai";s:5:"value";s:5:"th_TH";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Turkish";s:5:"value";s:5:"tr_TR";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: a:3:{s:5:"label";s:10:"Vietnamese";s:5:"value";s:5:"vi_VN";s:8:"grouping";N;}
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: N;
CRM_Core_DAO: FETCH: Last Data Fetch'ed after 0.0016689300537109 seconds
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
DB Error: no such table
Return to home page.

CRM_Core_DAO: CONNECT: Checking for database specific ini ('') : database_ in options
CRM_Core_DAO: QUERY: SET NAMES utf8
CRM_Core_DAO: query: QUERY DONE IN 0.00045299530029297 seconds
```

---

I succeeded to enable the backtrace :

Here you go :

backTrace

```
#0 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: no such table", -18, 16, (Array:2), "\n        SELECT full_name, file\n        FROM civicrm_extension\n        WHE...")
#4 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-18, 16, (Array:2), "\n        SELECT full_name, file\n        FROM civicrm_extension\n        WHE...")
#5 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -18, NULL, NULL, "\n        SELECT full_name, file\n        FROM civicrm_extension\n        WHE...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(899): DB_common->raiseError(-18, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1146 ** Table 'fxjp_cvacharleroibe.civicrm_extension' doesn't exist")
#7 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
#8 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("\n        SELECT full_name, file\n        FROM civicrm_extension\n        WHE...")
#9 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("\n        SELECT full_name, file\n        FROM civicrm_extension\n        WHE...")
#10 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("\n        SELECT full_name, file\n        FROM civicrm_extension\n        WHE...")
#11 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(325): DB_DataObject->query("\n        SELECT full_name, file\n        FROM civicrm_extension\n        WHE...")
#12 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1179): CRM_Core_DAO->query("\n        SELECT full_name, file\n        FROM civicrm_extension\n        WHE...", TRUE)
#13 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Mapper.php(300): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("\n        SELECT full_name, file\n        FROM civicrm_extension\n        WHE...")
#14 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/PseudoConstant.php(1837): CRM_Extension_Mapper->getActiveModuleFiles(FALSE)
#15 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(247): CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::getModuleExtensions()
#16 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(165): CRM_Utils_Hook->requireCiviModules((Array:1))
#17 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(137): CRM_Utils_Hook->commonBuildModuleList("joomla")
#18 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/Joomla.php(102): CRM_Utils_Hook->commonInvoke(1, Object(CRM_Core_Config), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_config", "joomla")
#19 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(1043): CRM_Utils_Hook_Joomla->invoke(1, Object(CRM_Core_Config), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_config")
#20 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php(257): CRM_Utils_Hook::config(Object(CRM_Core_Config))
#21 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/admin.civicrm.php(66): CRM_Core_Config::singleton()
#22 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/admin.civicrm.php(80): civicrm_initialize()
#23 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/admin.civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
#24 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php(380): require_once("/home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/c...")
#25 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php(348): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/components/c...")
#26 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/includes/application.php(153): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#27 /home/clients/a668016378523b2aa52441a2e692c8e7/web/administrator/index.php(46): JAdministrator->dispatch()
#28 {main}

DÃ©tails additionnels:
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -18
    [message] => DB Error: no such table
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => 
        SELECT full_name, file
        FROM civicrm_extension
        WHERE is_active = 1
        AND type = "module"
       [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'fxjp_cvacharleroibe.civicrm_extension' doesn't exist]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => 
        SELECT full_name, file
        FROM civicrm_extension
        WHERE is_active = 1
        AND type = "module"
       [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'fxjp_cvacharleroibe.civicrm_extension' doesn't exist]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="
        SELECT full_name, file
        FROM civicrm_extension
        WHERE is_active = 1
        AND type = "module"
       [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'fxjp_cvacharleroibe.civicrm_extension' doesn't exist]"]
)
```

---

Goodmorning everyone,

I have just tried to upgrade again my Civi after restoring my Civi (and it worked well at that time).

So, I followed the whole process step by step but I get again the same error.

Actually the installation works well. I got the succeed message of this but after that I tried to run the page : http://www.cva-charleroi.be/test/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1 and it gave me a error 001 Civi : `CiviCRM 4.6.4 requires MySQL trigger privileges`

If I now click on the CiviCRM button I get the same than previously :

```
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -18
    [message] => DB Error: no such table
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => 
        SELECT full_name, file
        FROM civicrm_extension
        WHERE is_active = 1
        AND type = "module"
       [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'fxjp_cvacharleroibetest.civicrm_extension' doesn't exist]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => 
        SELECT full_name, file
        FROM civicrm_extension
        WHERE is_active = 1
        AND type = "module"
       [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'fxjp_cvacharleroibetest.civicrm_extension' doesn't exist]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="
        SELECT full_name, file
        FROM civicrm_extension
        WHERE is_active = 1
        AND type = "module"
       [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'fxjp_cvacharleroibetest.civicrm_extension' doesn't exist]"]
)
```

What have I to do ?

Thanks a lot for you help !

---

Ah, and by the way, lolcode, I want to upgrade from a 4.1.5 to the newest one.

---

CiviCRM runs on Joomla 2.5.28 (upgrading it is panned) with PHP 5.4 (5.5 and 5.6 available) and MySQL 5.5

Comment: You could enable debuging and show backtrace in CiviCRM. This does show a backtrace of the error and the backtrace includes the failing query and why it is failing. In other words it will show which table is missing. To enable the backtrace in CiviCRM you go to Administer --> System Settings --> Debug

Comment: OK. But I cannot access to any part of CiviCRM. How can I do that ?

Comment: @Anolis Can you please add which version you are upgrading from and upgrading to in your answer? Also when does the error occur: Right away when you launch the upgrade? At the end of a seemingly successful upgrade?

If possible with your account it would be better to add the backtrace below to your question rather than post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have a serious database error after installing an upgrade the best approach is to restore the previous version from the backups taken before the upgrade as follows:

1. Delete all tables, views and procedures in the database with the error.
2. Restore the pre-upgrade database by importing it (using PHPMyadmin or mysql command line for example)
3. Restore the previous version of the civicrm code

Now you can run the upgrade again and try to determine at what point it fails.

If you do not have a backup then you will need a different approach.

In this case it sounds like you have 2 specific problems:

1. You may need to give MySQL TRIGGER permissions to the user specified in your civicrm.settings.php database connection.
2. You may be affected by a bug in the upgrade process.

**Regarding 1:**
See [the wiki](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+MySQL+Permission+Requirements) for reference:

```
-- Assuming a database called "civicrm" and a user called "civicrm_user"
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX,
ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, TRIGGER,
CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON civicrm.* 
TO 'civicrm_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'realpasswordhere';
```

**Regarding 2:**
A bug related to upgrading from the 4.1 series was reported [here on the forum](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=29373.0) and you may be able to use the workaround noted there:

> 'civicrm_extension' doesn't exist on upgrade from 4.1.6 to 4.3.5
>   ....(I) worked around by commenting out the public static function
>   &getExtensions() in CRM/Core/PseudoConstant.php,

Alternately you could upgrade in stages which is often a good approach. Upgrade from 4.15 to the latest version of 4.2. If that is successful take another full backup of the database and code before proceeding further. Now upgrade to the latest version.

By doing the upgrade in smaller stages you are taking advantage of the fact the the upgrade is more heavily tested on the previous one or two versions.

Comment: OK. I will try it and upgrade Civi again step by step.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. 
So, now, I came back again on my stable version 4.1.5 and I decided to upgraded step by step (it will be long !).
As the 4.1.6 is concerned, I don't see any issue. But, till the 4.2 upgrade I already get a prob when I click on a contact name :

    Error Table 'fxjp_cvacharleroibetest.civicrm_sms_provider' doesn't exist, 1146
         
What can I do ? Apperently Civi doesn't create any new table, isn't ?

Comment: @Anolis It really does sound like you need to take care of the MySQL permissions issue. Are there any errors in the web server, CiviCRM or Joomla logs?

Answer (score 1):

are you using MySQL for your DB?  You got from 4.1.5 to 4.1.6 without errors logged - when you upgrade to 4.2, even before going to the CiviCRM Dashboard - can you go into MySQL and do 'show tables' and are they the same number/name of tables as your 4.1.5, do you see 'civicrm_sms_provider'?  As lolcode above asked, did you grant all on your database 'user' (can you, for example, log in to that database and create a table (just a test)?
Maybe I should ask, are you comfortable using SQL?

Comment: I went to my DB via phpmyadmin and I saw - on the 4.1.6 - that there is no 'civicrm_sms_provider' so it was no created during the upgrade.
Sorry but I'm note super comfortable using SQL so I'm a bit lost to grant all on mydatabase 'user'. What does that mean concretely ? Thanks !